# redirect to login page if no call ajax angularjs

Tags: ajax, angularjs

In my script.js i have to redirect to login page if no ajax call, but i have response.status = 200 !

```
myapp.factory('myHttpResponseInterceptor',['$q','$location',function($q,$location){

        return {
            response: function(response) {
                return response;
            }, responseError: function(response) {
                if (response.status === 401)
                    $location.url('/login');
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        }

    }]);

    myapp.config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpResponseInterceptor');
    }]);
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is. This will, on response error, redirect to the login page. If it's a good response it will simply return the response. If you're receiving a response status of 200 then it's a good response so it returns the response. If you shouldn't be receiving that, then the error is located in whatever API you're calling, not the interceptor.

Comment: I made ​​the call JSON data from mvc5 API, What I want to do here is to test if I have access for json data , return response if not redirect to connected

Comment: Okay, so the interceptor as it is right now will do that. You would need to configure your API to return the 401 response. Right now it's returning 200 as you noted in your question, so the interceptor is never doing the redirect. Can you post the code in your API?

Comment: in response.data i have the html of login page ! how can i resolve this problem

Comment: What you have to do is **to configure your API to return 401 status code** as Ben Black mentioned above.